# How to make a meta box field a requirement

Tags: metabox

I'm building a plugin that has a meta box. Some of the fields in the meta box are required. Is using jQuery the only method for achieving this? Can I require that a field is filled in using PHP?

Comment: You can either fill it with a default value, or check if the field is empty, maybe provide the user a notice on that, and don't allow for/apply the default functionality. But maybe you could get a more detailed and useful answer if you provided more information...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Javascript to create a first-line convenience warning, but that is not a secure solution. You will need to interrupt the post save to truly create a required field.

```
function req_meta_wpse_96762($data){
  $allow_pending = false;
  if (isset($_POST['meta'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['meta'] as $v) {
      if ('your_required_key' === $v['key'] && !empty($v['value'])) {
        $allow_pending = true;
      }
    }
  }
  if (false === $allow_pending) {
    $data['post_status'] = 'draft';
  }
  return $data;
}
add_action('wp_insert_post_data','req_meta_wpse_96762');
```

That will also reset the post to 'Draft' if the meta field is deleted.

Comment: Fine idea, but as written, this will have side effects. wp_insert_post_data is called when a post is trashed, for instance, and this will break the trash by setting the status to "draft" instead.

You need to check if (@$data['post_status'] != 'publish') at the beginning, or check another field to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to require input per PHP. Only the browser can do that, and the browser gets the output after PHP is done.

You can add the attribute `required`:

```
<input name=foo required>
```

But not all browsers support that, and you have to check the value still in your validation handler.

Comment: The WP publish button seems to ignore this when I created my own meta box.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but it's first result on Google... Here my two cents:

Remember add all javascript fields validations before.

Thanks to @s_ha_dum answer, this is my custom meta box validation method:

```
        public static function validateMetaBoxesFields($postData, $postArray) {
        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
            return $postData;
        }
        if (array_key_exists('post_type', $postData) && $postData['post_type'] === 'MY_POST_TYPE') {
            if (array_key_exists('post_status', $postData) && $postData['post_status'] === 'publish') {
                $valid = true;
                // Check meta box fields (in $postArray) if something not valid, set $valid to false;
                if (!$valid) {
                    $postData['post_status'] = 'draft';
                    add_filter('redirect_post_location', array (self::class, 'alterRedirectMessageOnEventSave'));
                }
            }
        }
        return $postData;
    }
```

Add filter:

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', array (EventsPostTypeService::class, 'validateMetaBoxesFields'), 99, 2);
```

Due WordPress is showning post saved message, I need to filter redirect post location query. This is the method:

```
        public static function alterRedirectMessageOnEventSave($location) {
        $location = remove_query_arg('message', $location);
        // 550 or other number, @see wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php L:146 - 183
        $location = add_query_arg('message', 550, $location);
        return $location;
    }
```

And finally we add our custom message:

```
        public static function addCustomPostUpdateMessages($messages) {
        $messages['post'][550] = __('Post Type cannot be created due empty required fields: %s', 'my_text_domain');
        return $messages;
    }
```

%s can be replaced with a transient data, or other way you want to save not valid meta box fields.

Remember to add filter:

```
add_filter('post_updated_messages', array (EventsPostTypeService::class, 'addCustomPostUpdateMessages'), 10, 1);
```